# Email showing up in Top Deals but does not have full annotated experience with images

Tags: json, gmail-promo-tab

My test email with the annotation script comes through to the inbox and is showing as a Top Deal in the promo tab. However, I am not seeing the full experience with images and promotion markers. Any ideas on what could be the issue here? The code I used below had full image links and a discount code that I have removed when pasting here.

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
[{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "Organization",
    "logo": "https://.....png"
},{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "EmailMessage",
    "subjectLine": "Get 500 business cards for just $9.99"
},{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "DiscountOffer",
    "description": "50% off",
    "discountCode": "XXXXXX",
    "availabilityStarts": "2019-01-11T08:00:00-04:00",
    "availabilityEnds": "2019-01-25T08:00:00-04:00"
},{
    "@context": "http://schema.org/",
    "@type": "PromotionCard",
    "image": "http:.....jpg"
}]
</script>
```

Comment: Just seeing if anyone has an idea of what I can do to fix this. We're really excited to use this new functionality!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have the latest version of the Gmail App? Have you restarted your device since the last App update?

Also, if these default features are changed on your account then the features will not display: tabs and ads enabled, Images: Always show, Conversation view: On, and Enable Bundling of Top Email: On (some accounts may not have this last setting, if not ignore).

The code in the email needs to render and the expiration, if included, must start before send and end in the future. The email needs to be sent within a day and unopened to populate in the bundle.

There is a chance your email is in a holdback (create email ending in promotabtesting@gmail.com to test features if still not seeing them). Source [website](https://developers.google.com/gmail/promotab/overview).